# Looking for Pinyin/Traditional Characters eBooks

Tags: pinyin, traditional-characters

I am hoping that someone here can point me in the right direction. I am looking for some reading material so that I can practice my pronunciation. What I would like to find is the following:

A Reading Material that has the following features:

1. Is an eBook or Kindle book
2. Uses Pinyin and Traditional characters in alternating rows
3. Is novel length or at least a collection of short
   stories

I do not care if it has English translation or not, really. It is not for vocab building so much as having a substantial reading source that will allow me to read out loud to my wife and have her correct my pronunciation. Also, having the Pinyin and traditional characters one above the other in alternating rows will allow for a little bit of character recognition training.

Please let me know if there is anything like this that you know of anywhere. Thanks!

Update:  Searching Amazon I have found many books that combine pinyin and traditional characters, but they all have some flaw:  either the pinyin is on a separate page (not alternating rows) or it is not an ebook.  The search continues.

Update: I also found one app that alternates rows of pinyin and trad chars on the iPhone app store but it is subscription based and rather expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Your request of Pinyin and Traditional characters are in itself an oxymoron.

Pinyin is the system used in China and focuses on simplified characters. This system allows foreigners to learn Chinese a lot easier. 
Traditional Chinese characters use ㄅㄆㄇㄈ. A system that is only used in Taiwan.
Currently there's not much casual medium (novels, movies) that combines Traditional and Pinyin together. More educational mediums consists of text books provided by National Taiwan University. I believe they teach Chinese using the ㄅㄆㄇ system. The Bible and church hymns (if you are religious) occasionally has pinyin, but sometimes this type of pinyin is written in Wade-Giles and pronounced as Taiwanese (the dialect)

Comment: Searching Amazon I have found many books that combine pinyin and traditional characters, but they all have some flaw:  either the pinyin is on a separate page (not alternating rows) or it is not an ebook.  The search continues!

Comment: Very interesting, perhaps introducing pinyin to Taiwan might help foreigners bridge and help with the language barrier. Many have complained about the teaching system in Taiwan, and how it forces the foreigners to learn using the ㄅㄆㄇㄈ system. However, the current government and culture favors independence and might not be interested in teaching in pinyin.